# Build process failed on deployment to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I tried to deploy my flask application to Heroku. but get Push failed Message in response

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.6.9
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (68b932)…
-----> Installing SQLite3
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

What I tried:
According to a problem [here](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1802). Already Updated to heroku18 
 it tries to install SQLite3 even my pipfile does not have Requirement of SQLite3. I am using PostgreSQL for my application

Comment: Do you have more logs? It's relatively hard to know what the problem is from just this log.

Comment: nope.. application log redirecting me to build log and build log showing only this much.

Comment: is there any way to disable installing sqlite3?

Comment: Have you tried [clearing the buildpack cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) 

(when developing custom buildpacks, sometimes we broke the cache and had heroku to rebuild it)

I don't see a way to disable sqlite3 install [in the buildpack code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile#L285-L293)